# how to change toolbar icon (hamburger icon) when using navigation drawer with jetpack navigation component

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack, hamburger-menu, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using jetpack navigation component to build a navigation drawer, I want to change hamburger icon of the toolbar, I tried many solutions like bellow but they don't work

```
app:navigationIcon="@drawable/menu"
```

also

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu);
```

and this is my code

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    navController=findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    appBarConfiguration=AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.nav_acceuil,R.id.nav_notifications,R.id.nav_gerer,R.id.nav_deconnexion),drawer_layout)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
    nav_view.setupWithNavController(navController);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the **`addOnDestinationChangedListener`**:

```
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        if (destination.id == R.id.nav_xxxx){
            supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.xxxx)
        }
    }
```

Comment: FINALLY WORKS THAAANKS

Comment: While this magically works, it doesn't make sense, semantically. I'm from web world and i would understand if this implicitly is "DOM ready" kinda of trick in android world. Is it?

Comment: It's work for me, but why if we put this on onCreate() it's doesn't work?