# how to change Action bar icon (hamburger icon) when using navigation drawer with navigation component

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, hamburger-menu

I want to change the home up indicator but it doesn't work when using navigation component

I tried the solution from here and didn't work
[how to change toolbar icon (hamburger icon) when using navigation drawer with jetpack navigation component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217399/how-to-change-toolbar-icon-hamburger-icon-when-using-navigation-drawer-with-je)

My Code

```
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.myTeamFragment,
            R.id.myTasksFragment, R.id.meetingsFragment, R.id.freeTimeFragment, R.id.dashboardFilterFragment)
            .setOpenableLayout(binding.getRoot())
            .build();
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.toolbar, getNavController(), appBarConfiguration);
```

then as Solution Mentioned

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    getNavController().addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> {
        if (destination.getId() == R.id.dest0
                || destination.getId() == R.id.dest1
                || destination.getId() == R.id.dest2
                || destination.getId() == R.id.dest3
                || destination.getId() == R.id.dest4){

            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_hambergur_menu);
        } else {
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_hambergure_back);
        }
    });
```

Comment: does `addOnDestinationChangedListener()` callback get called?

Comment: Yes i debugged it it called, action bar not null and follow the right conditions

Comment: The answer linked in the question is not the same case. You are using a setup with a Toolbar. The linked question works with ActionBar API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a setup with a `Toolbar`

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.toolbar, getNavController(), appBarConfiguration);
```

Then use the Toolbar API instead of ActionBar API:

```
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        if (destination.id == R.id.nav_home){
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.xxxx)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, why? But for me it works with **postDelay** function. Even if I setup the **delay** equals *zero*

```
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        if (destination.id == R.id.fragment_orders) {
            view.postDelayed(
                {
                    supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_amount)
                },
                0
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Adding a handler with post delay 0 mili worked for me.**

```java
  @Override
    public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
                                     @NonNull NavDestination destination,
                                     @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestinationChanged: current destination: "+navController.getCurrentDestination().getLabel());
        this.currentFragmentId = destination.getId();
        if(currentFragmentId == R.id.addItemFragment){
            new Handler().postDelayed(()->{
                mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_back_ios_24);
            },0);
        }
        super.setTitle(destination.getLabel());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the back arrow button instead of the burger button, you can remove the fragments that you want to show the back button from `appBarConfiguration`

In your snippet, the back button won't show up in these fragemnts ( `R.id.myTasksFragment, R.id.meetingsFragment, R.id.freeTimeFragment, R.id.dashboardFilterFragment`), remove any of them to show the back button instead.

```
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.myTeamFragment,
        R.id.myTasksFragment, R.id.meetingsFragment, R.id.freeTimeFragment, R.id.dashboardFilterFragment)
        .setOpenableLayout(binding.getRoot())
        .build();
```

Comment: no this is my home fragment which i don't want to show the back button in it